# Why was this closed?

Tags: discussion

[This was closed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180988/what-is-the-word-for-poignant-but-with-a-positive-connotation) because of the 'misconception' that poignant carries negative connotations. I found it because I was going to ask something similar.

I didn't think it carried a negative connotation, but it does convey sadness and possibly regret.

Sadness isn't (by most standards) positive, and certainly regret isn't. The OP wanted something more *positive*. Poignant implies a strong feeling but I believe the OP meant, what's a strong feeling that doesn't carry a sad or regretful connotation? They just said 'negative' instead.

Have I missed something? Is the question, in that light, still off base or off-topic?

Comment: It's also conventional that you give a sentence you would like to use the suggestions in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking:

- Questions which make no sense, to the point that they can't be answered usefully, should be closed "unclear".
- Questions which do make sense but still rest on an error or misunderstanding can perhaps be answered by pointing out the error, provided that the resulting Q&A are useful.

I personally agree this question does not rest on an error or misunderstanding.

But I wouldn't reopen this question just yet. One of the closevotes was for lack of demonstrated research and clearly that's the case. if someone feels the question demands an expert answer and wants to do the research and edit the question to include evidence of research effort, then surely it could be reopened.

Comment: Great. Thanks Ed(?).